# Run an event when Checkbox is Checked/Unchecked Gridview C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a Gridview that has 4 columns. All in `ItemTemplate` One column is a CheckBox. This Gridview is binded to a datasource. What I want to do is when the Checkbox is checked update the database with the bit value '1' and if I uncheck the Checkbox to do the same but '0'.

I already know my SQL code to update the database, but I am not sure how to run the event so that it looks at the current row the checkbox is on in the gridview.

Here is the CheckBox Column.

```
<asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Pick" ItemStyle-CssClass="hrGrid" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hdrHrBase">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox id="cbViewCustomer" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="ViewCustomer" onAutoPostBack="true" Checked='<%#(Eval("chosen"))%>'/>        
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Do I use EventArgs like this:
The problem with this is it updates the database but all the rows.
What I am trying to do is update only the current row that is in the Gridview.  I am just not sure where to go from here.

```
protected void ViewCustomer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string SelectCustomer = "UPDATE tblcustomer Set chosen ='0'";
        NpgsqlCommand changedata = new NpgsqlCommand(SelectCustomer, con);
        con.Open();
        changedata.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
```

Or should I be doing something different?

Comment: Have you tried this? That is a valid solution. Although you should consider if you want to do this immediately... Usually users assume they can edit things as draft and only save when clicking a save button, make sure this is not the case and users understand checking the box will IMMEDIATELY update the object as I have found this can stress people out

Comment: As it is this updates the entire column with the same value. I just what it to update the current row.

Comment: What? You need to post the other code which does the update... You can certainly do what you need with an event handler like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `OnRowCommand` event of gridview like this:-

Associate a RowCommand event with your gridview:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="mygridview" runat="server" OnRowCommand="mygridview_OnRowCommand">
```

Next, associate a `CommandName` & `CommandArgument` to your checkbox:-

```
<asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Pick" ItemStyle-CssClass="hrGrid" >
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:CheckBox id="cbViewCustomer" runat="server" Checked='<%#(Eval("chosen"))%>' 
         CommandName="myCheckbox" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>"/>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In the code behind handle the event:-

```
protected mygridview_OnRowCommand (object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
     if(e.CommandName == "myCheckbox")
     {
          int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
          GridViewRow row = mygridview.Rows[rowIndex];
          bool ischecked = (row.FindControl("cbViewCustomer") as CheckBox).Checked;
     }
}
```

You can also do it with checbox checked event, but if you have multiple controls then fire the gridview command event instead of individual events.

Comment: The case returns this error:  Error CS8070: Control cannot fall out of switch statement through final case label `case "cbViewCustomer":' (CS8070) (sbmanager)

Comment: @TommyMcGee - That was just a _C# case statement_ issue which I gave for example. you can use the updated code instead.

Comment: I have been trying your suggestion but I cannot seem to get it to work. No error. just nothing happens.  I have OnRowCommand set on the gridview and the CommandName set on the checkbox. But still nothing happens.

Comment: @TommyMcGee - Have you debugged the code? Is it hitting the `mygridview_OnRowCommand ` event handler?